# In Julia, how to merge a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, merge, julia

What is the best way to merge a dictionary in Julia?

```
> dict1 = Dict("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3)
> dict2 = Dict("d" => 4, "e" => 5, "f" => 6)
# merge both dicts
> dict3 = dict1 with dict2
> dict3
Dict{ASCIIString,Int64} with 6 entries:
  "f" => 6
  "c" => 3
  "e" => 5
  "b" => 2
  "a" => 1
  "d" => 4
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/collections/#Base.merge

```
merge(collection, others...)

Construct a merged collection from the given collections. If necessary, the types of the resulting collection will be promoted to accommodate the types of the merged collections. If the same key is present in another collection, the value for that key will be the value it has in the last collection listed.

julia> merge(dict1,dict2)
    Dict{ASCIIString,Int64} with 6 entries:
      "f" => 6
      "c" => 3
      "e" => 5
      "b" => 2
      "a" => 1
      "d" => 4

merge!(collection, others...)
Update collection with pairs from the other collections.

julia> merge!(dict1,dict2)
Dict{ASCIIString,Int64} with 6 entries:
  "f" => 6
  "c" => 3
  "e" => 5
  "b" => 2
  "a" => 1
  "d" => 4

julia> dict1
Dict{ASCIIString,Int64} with 6 entries:
  "f" => 6
  "c" => 3
  "e" => 5
  "b" => 2
  "a" => 1
  "d" => 4
```

Comment: Just out if curiosity, how would thus handle conflicting key values? If I have values 'a =5' in 'dict1' and 'a =7' in 'dict2' what would the value of 'a' be in the resulting dictionary?

Comment: If you wanted to keep the conflicting values, you could use `union(dict1, dict2)`; however, this would return an `Array` rather than a `Dict`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`merge`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.merge). If the `Dict`s have elements with the same key, the value for that key will be of the last `Dict` listed.

If you want to combine the elements of the `Dict`s that have the same key, you can use `mergewith(combine, collection, others...)`. `combine` is a function that receive two values and return a value. See [`mergewith`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.mergewith).

Example of the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.mergewith):

```
julia> a = Dict("foo" => 0.0, "bar" => 42.0)
Dict{String,Float64} with 2 entries:
  "bar" => 42.0
  "foo" => 0.0

julia> b = Dict("baz" => 17, "bar" => 4711)
Dict{String,Int64} with 2 entries:
  "bar" => 4711
  "baz" => 17

julia> mergewith(+, a, b)
Dict{String,Float64} with 3 entries:
  "bar" => 4753.0
  "baz" => 17.0
  "foo" => 0.0
```

Comment: So if I would like to keep the second element, can I use `merge((x, y) -> y, a, b)`?

Comment: I think this would work, but you can use `merge(a, b)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `...` operator, like this:

```
julia> dict1 = Dict("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3);

julia> dict2 = Dict("d" => 4, "e" => 5, "f" => 6);

julia> Dict(dict1..., dict2...)
Dict{String, Int64} with 6 entries:
  "f" => 6
  "c" => 3
  "e" => 5
  "b" => 2
  "a" => 1
  "d" => 4
```

Comment: Neat! Works for Vectors and Sets too.